# Use dynamic number of hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks

Let's say I have a hook, useX() that returns some states and functions. I do an API request that returns some (dynamic amount of) strings (for example, "a" and "b").

I want to have a dictionary mapping these strings to instances of useX(), something like: x = {a: useX(), b: useX()}, so I can do actions like x.a.someFunction() or x.a.someState.

I know React doesn't let you call hooks inside loops, so I wonder whether this is even possible at all. Please help!

Comment: Not sure what's your exact use case. But if I understand it correctly you could create one hook that is handling your events. Something like in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-brahmagupta-sddx3w?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're facing is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info), you've found a problem and figured out that this is the solution, and you asked your question about the solution, not the original question..

Your problem is that you want to use "Dynamic number of hook calls.

Is this possible? **No**.

However, is this the solution? still a **No**

Your solution is basically to use one big hook or multiple hooks to solve your problem.

What's I've understood from your problem though is that you want something like events, in this case, see [Redux](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsa4EjQAXAYCX9ssOAuBE_WZcdYNRg:1653680965893&q=redux&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjivKzUuYD4AhXTtqQKHdGJBOcQBSgAegQIARAx&biw=1512&bih=805&dpr=2)